# Substring in a django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

How do i display a substring in a django template? The following doesn't seem to work, I am trying to display the first 3 letters and the next 3 in another line:

```
{{ obj.name[0:3] }}
{{ obj.name[4:8] }}
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use the [`slice`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) template filter:

```
{{ obj.name|slice:"0:3" }}
```

Comment: Tanks, I solved my problem. :D

Comment: Given link doesn't work, current docs can be found at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#slice